# How do i access my youtube brand account api?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

Been trying to access YT analytics api for brand accounts through nodejs server using googleapis library but it returns forbidden. I have created a service account under my gmail manager id but no success.

Comment: Could you provide a code example, with auth keys dummied out? See [mcve] for more details.

Comment: Hey I read in the analytics-API documentation that **The YouTube Analytics API does not support the service account flow.** So the question now becomes what redirect uri should i use fo my nodejs oauth callback